# Filter negative and positive values out of one variable in PHP

Tags: php, summary

I have a variable in PHP where values from a database are inserted. It’s about money. I need to summarize all negative and positives values separately.

Example:

```
February, I have:
+ 10
− 10
+100
− 50
− 15
+ 70
+ 80
—
Credits added: 260 Euro
Credits paid: −75 Euro
```

The variable is named `$amound` in my PHP file. I really have no clue how to do that.

In Excel, this would be as follows: `=SUMMEWENN(E1:E48;"<0")`

But here I only have a *variable*, not fields.

Heres some Code:

```
$reportdata["tableheadings"] = array("Transaktions-ID","Kunde","Datum","Beschreibung","Betrag");

if ($startdate && $enddate) {

$query = "SELECT tblcredit.*,tblclients.firstname,tblclients.lastname FROM tblcredit INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblcredit.clientid WHERE tblcredit.date BETWEEN '".db_make_safe_human_date($startdate)."' AND '".db_make_safe_human_date($enddate)."'";
$result = full_query($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $data["id"];
    $userid = $data["clientid"];
    $clientname = $data["firstname"]." ".$data["lastname"];
    $date = fromMySQLDate($data["date"]);
    $description = $data["description"];
    $amount = $data["amount"];
    $currency = getCurrency($userid);
    $amount = formatCurrency($amount);
    $overallamount += $amount;
  //  $overallamountout -= $amount;
  //  $overallamountin += $overallamount > 0;
    $reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array($id,'<a href="clientssummary.php?userid='.$userid.'">'.$clientname.'</a>',$date,nl2br($description),$amount);
}
```

Comment: Is that var a string, or an array?

Comment: Show us *some* attempt at coding this, please?

Comment: You’re free to name your variables as you please, but note that it’s *amount* and not *amound*.

Comment: Show us the `var_dump` output of that variable!

Comment: I posted some Code, i'm not sure if its a string or a VAR. of course its the $amount i meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

its done. 
Heres the Code which was used:

```
$summeGesamt = 0;
$summeEingezahlt = 0;
$summeAusgezahlt = 0;

$summeGesamt = $summeGesamt + $data["amount"];
if ( $data["amount"] >= 0) {
  $summeEingezahlt += $data["amount"];
} else {
  $summeAusgezahlt +=  $data["amount"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is very simple (I assume that all of your variables are strings, e.g. coming from a text file, but even if not it will work):

```
$var1 = '+80';
$var2 = '-30';

$result = (int)$var1 + (int)$var2;

var_dump($result);
```

Will result in: "int(50)" => Working fine.

Comment: i think i can only have $amount, please see the Code in my Post

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the DB

```
SELECT SUM(numbers) AS sum1 FROM pepa WHERE numbers > 0;
SELECT SUM(numbers) AS sum2 FROM pepa WHERE numbers < 0;
```

Comment: hi, i'm not sure how to use this. I posted some Code to show current state